# Bitcore.io Create a raw tx hex (signed) to push to the blockchain

Tags: raw-transaction, bitcore

I am trying to push a raw transaction to blockr.io **testnet** using bitcore (current latest version 0.12.9) for node.js https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore

I have constructed my transaction like so:

```
var unspents=
[ { txid: '67b22a1874be2e748b2c904e2181f85a9d6503001e58c374e17b1161cd5a36f4',
    vout: 0,
    address: 'myHtNgECiAjBctWz1tM2TN2PupWwfHtgMi',
    scriptPubKey: '76a914c2f9958848c465efd042fcb76fef519f03a83ec288ac',
    amount: 100000,
    confirmations: 39 } ];



    var transaction=new bitcore.Transaction()
    .fee(bitcore.Unit.fromBTC(0.0001).toSatoshis())
    .from(unspents) // there is one unspent of 0.001
    .to(bitcore.Address.fromString(payToAddress),0.001)
    .change(myAddress)
    .sign(privateKey);



console.log(transaction.isFullySigned()); // This returns true
```

When I POST this to blockr.io I serialize it:

```
'https://'+'t'+'btc.blockr.io/api/v1/tx/push'    // < t at the beginning is for testnet

{'hex':transaction.serialize()} // 0100000001f4365acd61117be174c3581e0003659d5af881214e902c8b742ebe74182ab267000000006a47304402204f5950a8f8e7346e96101da811452246d51741131310f58d5cfdc064e547d3dc02202b817a442bb043a1174fe0703082ebbd7bc622afc00084710be21fa143444d83012102bbe798da887604bdd360dd059061b48816634e44d9f54563af2c727b8bcb3e2fffffffff02a08601000000000017a9149ffdff1f3eea0deb21ed967b91c7ef3cce65b2d68750f2704e180900001976a914c2f9958848c465efd042fcb76fef519f03a83ec288ac00000000
```

The response I get back from blockr.io is:

```
[ { status: 'fail',
    data: 'Could not push your transaction!',
    code: 500,
    message: 'Did you sign your transaction?' },
  500 ]
```

Below is the transaction I sent but as JSON. I'm thinking there is something wrong with it?

```
{
"version":1,
"inputs":
[{
    "prevTxId":"67b22a1874be2e748b2c904e2181f85a9d6503001e58c374e17b1161cd5a36f4",
    "outputIndex":0,
    "sequenceNumber":4294967295,
    "script":"47304402204f5950a8f8e7346e96101da811452246d51741131310f58d5cfdc064e547d3dc02202b817a442bb043a1174fe0703082ebbd7bc622afc00084710be21fa143444d83012102bbe798da887604bdd360dd059061b48816634e44d9f54563af2c727b8bcb3e2f",
    "scriptString":"71 0x304402204f5950a8f8e7346e96101da811452246d51741131310f58d5cfdc064e547d3dc02202b817a442bb043a1174fe0703082ebbd7bc622afc00084710be21fa143444d8301 33 0x02bbe798da887604bdd360dd059061b48816634e44d9f54563af2c727b8bcb3e2f",
    "output":{
        "satoshis":10000000000000,
        "script":"76a914c2f9958848c465efd042fcb76fef519f03a83ec288ac"
    }
}]
,"outputs":
[{
    "satoshis":100000,
    "script":"a9149ffdff1f3eea0deb21ed967b91c7ef3cce65b2d687"
},{
    "satoshis":9999999890000,
    "script":"76a914c2f9958848c465efd042fcb76fef519f03a83ec288ac"
}]
,"nLockTime":0,
"changeScript":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 20 0xc2f9958848c465efd042fcb76fef519f03a83ec2 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
"changeIndex":1,
"fee":10000
```

}

I signed it with my private key then serialized it as blockr wants it in hex format does this mean I have got to somehow sign it after it's serialized or what?

And what is the deal with these large numbers:

```
"satoshis":10000000000000,

"satoshis":9999999890000,
```

**UPDATE:**

Block chain info instead returns this error:

```
Unable To find all tx inputs [67b22a1874be2e748b2c904e2181f85a9d6503001e58c374e17b1161cd5a36f4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
amount: 100000,
```

The amount is supposed to be in coins, not satoshis, according [these comments](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/blob/master/lib/transaction/transaction.js#L495-L506) in the code. To fix it, replace that line with

```
satoshis: 100000,
```

> And what is the deal with these large numbers:

Since the code was assuming an input with 100,000 coins in the inputs, the change address had a lot more coins in it than there should have been.